# Proving Subtraction without using it??

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Definition: $(a, b) \sim (c, d)$ iff $a + d = b + c$. Explain how this relation represents subtraction. (Do not prove that it's an equivalence relation.)

I'm not sure how to answer this/what the final step looks like so any help would be appreciated. I believe you set each side equal to a single variable first? Could be completely wrong

Comment: my bad. its my first post; ill fix it next time

Comment: I think the question statement is under-specified; "represents subtraction" seems a bit arbitrary, so I understand your confusion.

Note that $a+d=b+c$ means the same as $a-b=c-d$. I would maybe start there.

Comment: @Charlie exactly where I go wrong. I'm supposed to explain how this shows subtraction or the idea of subtraction without using it; therefore I can't show how those are the same thing. I think I'm meant to start by setting a+d=e or something and proving that this relation somehow outlines subtraction? I don't know if that gives you any better idea on how to proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're supposed to show that this is the same as subtraction without even referencing what subtraction is in the first place... I'll note that this is usually how you define $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$, by letting $\mathbb{Z}\colon= \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}/\sim$. Are you sure this isn't supposed to be explaining *negative numbers*, not subtraction? A relation isn't an operation...

Comment: @Charlie. This is all the instructions I have; it might just be another way to define Z actually...if you want to expand on that? Otherwise: "But, since
we can't subtract in N we will arrive at subtraction through addition. We begin by defining a relation ~ on N x N.
Definition: (a, b) ~ (c, d) iff a + d = b + c.
Explain how this relation represents subtraction.
I believe I can reference subtraction, but can't perform it on the numbers. Also I'm confused on how the two directions of the iff work. Not sure if this clarifies?

Comment: I'll just second what @Charlie said: this is the usual definition of negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting this question as charitably as possible. Unfortunately, it seems from the comments that your instructor has provided you with vague instructions.

The relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ allows you to represent subtraction as follows: for a given natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$, write $n$ as $[(n,0)]$ (the equivalence class of $(n, 0)$). Then for any two natural numbers $n, m$, we can simply define $n-m = [(n, 0)]- [(m, 0)] = [(n, m)]$. One can easily check that this is well-defined. This interpretation of subtraction hinges on the idea of $(a, b)$ being considered "large" if $a$ is much bigger than $b$. It also allows the representation of negative numbers by using pairs where $b>a$.

That's about the best I can give from the context provided; since a relation isn't an operation, all I can really do is show you how the operation is actually defined. But my real advice is to ask for clarification from your instructor directly.

Comment: Ok! I'll mention this idea to him and ask for more clarification. Thanks!